# Trying to get my span text to be bold and have a bigger font

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my span to be bold and have a different font than my paragraph. The CSS is correctly linked to my html.

```css
span.bold {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 22px;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <span="bold">Welcome to Coding Club for Web Developers</span> <br> Coding Club web developers is specifically designed to teach the basics of making a website by learning HTML, Javascript, and CSS. Using Discord, we talk with our team to learn from each other and
    to design for our upcoming projects. As a beginner or an amateur, you'll learn everything you need to know about Web Development. To practice, you can go to W3Schools, Sololearn, or Codecademy. <br>
```

Comment: What's `<span="bold">`? Did you mean `<span class="bold">`?

Comment: [That's what it is](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/pdbMBX)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `class` keyword `span=bold` doesn't mean anything

```css
span.bold {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 22px;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <span class="bold">Welcome to Coding Club for Web Developers</span> <br> Coding Club web developers is specifically designed to teach the basics of making a website by learning HTML, Javascript, and CSS. Using Discord, we talk with our team to learn from each other and
    to design for our upcoming projects. As a beginner or an amateur, you'll learn everything you need to know about Web Development. To practice, you can go to W3Schools, Sololearn, or Codecademy. <br>
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed <span= "bold"> to <span class="bold">, but still it doesn't work

Comment: I see why. I did inspect element and and looked at my CSS. Its still says <span="bold">. I opened up my file again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a class named `bold` to `span` element, you do it with:

```
<span class="bold">
```

not with

```
<span="bold">
```